# Convert SQL to Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Let's say I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM drivers where driver_number NOT IN (SELECT driver_number FROM buses) AND station_id = 2 OR driver_number = 'Dr_02'
```

and it displays this data
[image]

Then i want to get this data as laravel query and here is what I did:

```
$drivers = Driver::whereRaw('driver_number not in (select driver_number from buses) AND station_id = ? ', [$station_id].' OR id = ?', [$bus->Driver_id])
                    ->get();
```

But I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'driver_number
>   not in (select driver_number from buses) AND station_id = ?' at line 1
>   (SQL: select * from `drivers` where id = 2 driver_number not in
>   (select driver_number from buses) AND station_id = ?)

I think there is error the way put it, that's it gets a type system error. So if anyone knows a better way to do it, you can help.

Comment: Please add parentheses to your `WHERE` clause to make it unambiguous.

Comment: you can try $task_without_due_date = \DB::select(\DB::raw("your query)); this also

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky to handle in Laravel.  The logic in your `WHERE` clause is basically `(A and B) or C`, where condition `A` can be represented by a `NOT EXISTS` subquery in MySQL.

```
$drivers = DB::table('Driver d')
    ->where(function($query1) {
        return $query1
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query2) {
                $query2->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('buses b')
                    ->whereRaw('d.driver_number = b.driver_number');
              })
            ->where('station_id', '=', '2');
    })
    ->orWhere('driver_number', '=', 'Dr_02');
->get();
```

Comment: thanks for ur replay, but your answer is showing this `compact(): Undefined variable: operator`

Comment: @Lafoune What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 5.5, is the problem with the version I'm using?

Comment: I can't test my code at the moment.  My answer and running the enitre query as a raw query are the only two possibilities I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
$task_without_due_date = \DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT * FROM drivers where driver_number NOT IN (SELECT driver_number FROM buses) AND station_id = '.$station_id.' OR driver_number = '.$bus->Driver_id.'"));
```

Comment: when i run it like this it won't retrun anything but `[ ]`. but when i remove  `AND station_id = '.$station_id.'` it'll work but it will return data that i don't want.

Comment: Add OR and check bcoz I don't have exact code so how I can figure out

Comment: You can debug your query 
DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log

// Your Eloquent query

dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
$result = DB::table('drivers')
->whereNotIn('driver_number', function($q){
    $q->select('driver_number')->from('buses');
})
->where('station_id', '=', 2)
->where('driver_number', '=', 'Dr_02')
->get();
```